# Does multiple evaluations of an IQueryable object hit the Database multiple times?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the Entity Framework, if I do the following:

```
var count = myIQueryable.Count();
var list = myIQueryable.ToList();
```

does that hit the Database twice? or just once?

Comment: it should do, but in some cases it doesn't, I have seen this in EF core, it returned the same result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to effectively count the number of entries, the framework needs to evaluate the query, thus hitting the Database. However, because the query may have changed between the Count() and ToList(), it must evaluate again. Consider the following:

```
var myIQueryable = my.db<SomeModel>();  // IQueryable<SomeModel>
var countQuery = myIQueryable.Count();  // 10
MakeAdditions(myIQueryable, 10);        // adds 10 items
var list = myIQueryable.ToList();       // List<SomeModel> count=20
MakeAdditions(myIQueryable, 10);
var countList = list.Count();           // still 20, List never changed
```

Put another way, all calls against an IQueryable are still subject to the way it runs its queries. After capturing a query into a List, you are exclusively dealing with your in-memory List, independant of changes that occur to the IQueryable's data source.

Comment: So, even if you are making additions on the same evaluated IQueryable, adding a filter for instance, the IQueryable doesn't use its previous result?

Comment: Exactly, the nature of the IQueryable is evaulate the query when it is called. If you want to use a previous evaluation, you must capture it first. 'var list = myIQueryable.ToList(); MakeAdditions(); var count = list.Count();'

Comment: If you're not paging, may as well just get the results with ToList, then use its Count property so you're not hitting the database twice.  On the other hand, if you're paging data, then your ToList will have fewer results than Count, so you'd have to make two separate hits on the database.  I wonder, however, if there's any performance increase by calling Count then running the (paged) query, vs running the (paged) query then calling Count.  Does one in any way cache results or plans that would be useful?

Comment: @Triynko, true, there's normally no need to do the example above, it just shows how you could end up hitting the db (or IQueryable structure) twice. As per your question, I'm relatively sure .NET would not cache either way, the only way to achieve that result would be to save the resultant list of `.ToList()` and then call `.Count()` on _that_ list. You won't hit the db during the count then.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it does hit the database twice, as both `Count` and `ToList` are eagerly evaluated. If you just want to access it once, do the following:

```
var list = myIQueryable.ToList();
var count = list.Count;
```

Comment: I accepted MaxWell's answer because it has a bit more detail on it